# Kubernetes - Unable to hit the server

Tags: kubernetes

We deployed a containerized app by pulling a public docker image from docker hub and were able to get a pod running at a server running at 172.30.105.44. Hitting this IP from a rest client or curl/pinging the IP gives no response. Can someone please guide us where we are going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, find out the IP of your node by executing the command 
`kubectl get nodes`
Get the information related to the pod running by executing the command `kubectl describe services <pod-name>` 
Make a note of the field NodePort from here.
To access your service that is already running, hit the endpoint - nodeIP:NodePort.
You can now access your service successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you have deployed (AWS, GKE, Bare) but you should make sure you have the following:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/

Ingress will work out of the box on GKE, but with an AWS installation, you may need to make sure you have nginx-ingress pods running.